# Build runnable jar file for BDD Serenity Java project using Maven

Tags: maven, jar, bdd

I have built a BDD Serenity project in IntelliJ using  Maven 3.6.3. I need to build a runnable jar file so that the BDD tests can run on another laptop.

I run "mvn clean package" and I get the message "JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!"

Please help, I am not sure on how to resolve this issue. Below is the output, as well as the POM file.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< equalexperts:hotelbookings >---------------------
[INFO] Building Serenity project with JUnit and WebDriver 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ hotelbookings ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Intelli- Projects\serenity-tutorials\hotelbookings\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hotelbookings ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Intelli- Projects\serenity-tutorials\hotelbookings\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ hotelbookings ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ hotelbookings ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Intelli- Projects\serenity-tutorials\hotelbookings\test
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hotelbookings ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Intelli- Projects\serenity-tutorials\hotelbookings\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ hotelbookings ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ hotelbookings ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Intelli- Projects\serenity-tutorials\hotelbookings\target\hotelbookings-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.740 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-24T17:38:50+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>equalexperts</groupId>
<artifactId>hotelbookings</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Serenity project with JUnit and WebDriver</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>2.3.2</serenity.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray</name>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray-plugins</name>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->

</dependencies>
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>test</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>ServiceCreate</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.svt.optimoo.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/When*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Story.java</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The jar file is normally built by compiling the sources src/main.java. It is a bad practice to bundle the JAR from src/test/java and run it on another machine. There must be CI - Jenkins to do this job!

Answer (score 0):

It may be difficult to implement because of such things:

- test sources are not included by default into jar since they placed in special directory, following maven`s Convention-Over-Configuration
- every "runnable" jar must have the starter class with entry point (`public static void main(String[] args)` method)
- especially integration tests (run by maven-failsafe-plugin) or their parts may use resources inside `src/` dir, but not `target/test-classes` location, where static resources are placed by maven (`serenity-maven-plugin` does that for report generation)

Though all this points technically may be implemented I bielive, but there is no quarantee for repoduciable behaviour onto another machine with jar file.

Let me advice you to use CI tools, as tibor17 mentiones, or maybe hand-made script with smth like `git clone <repo>; cd <repo>; mvn verify`